# Exact determination of the probability distribution of a nonlinear function of two normally distributed variables, or of its standard deviation.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

As a part of a problem in the design of an electronics apparatus, I am trying to analyze the probability distribution of the following quantity
$$
\bar{g}_m=\frac{g_1g_2}{g_1+g_2}\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
from the point of view of its probabilistic behavior: parameters $g_1$ and $g_2$ (which are part of the small signal model of a semiconductor device) have normally distributed values (around their "nominal" one), and their correlation is $0$. I do not know the exact value of the standard deviation $\sigma_i$, $i=1,2$ of their value but I know their so called "matching" i.e. I know the value
$$
\frac{\Delta g_i}{g_i}=k\sigma_i>0\qquad i=1,2\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
where $k$ is an integer $\ge 6$ (these devices are produced in millions of units, so the devices which do not satisfy \eqref{2} and must be rejected during the test phase should be *less* than one part per million) and can be assumed constant for both $g_1$ and $g_2$: for the sake of precision, I can say that $\frac{\Delta g_1}{g_1}\simeq\frac{\Delta g_2}{g_2}\simeq 10\%$, even if this is not very useful from the point of view of the problem I am posing.
So **my question is**

*Is it possible to determine explicitly the probability distribution of $\bar{g}_m$, or at least a precise estimate for the matching $\frac{\Delta g_m}{g_m}$ from values of the matching of $g_1$ and $g_2$ expressed by \eqref{2}?*

As it can bee seen, the question is equivalent to ask if it is possible to determine explicitly (or at least sharply estimate) the standard deviation $\sigma_m$ of $\bar{g}_m$ from the knowledge of $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$.

**Notes**

- **What I know**: V. K. Rohatgi has developed a way of determine the probability distribution of the product of two random variables by using the [Mellin transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) of their distributions. However, \eqref{1} is not a simple product of random variables, but is a *nonlinear algebraic function of two random variables*, therefore a knowledge deeper than mine of the applicable probabilistic techniques may be required (read as: I am not an expert in applied probability).
- **What I customarily do in common designs and why I cannot proceed in the same way for this one**. The basis of the two methods I use (and, in my opinion, many other engineers customarily do) is the standard technique inherited from the theory of error propagation
  $$
  \mathrm{d}\bar{g}_m =\frac{\partial\bar{g}_m}{\partial g_1}\mathrm{d}g_1+\frac{\partial\bar{g}_m}{\partial g_2}\mathrm{d}g_2\implies
  \begin{align}
  \Delta\bar{g}_m &\simeq\frac{\partial\bar{g}_m}{\partial g_1}\Delta g_1+\frac{\partial\bar{g}_m}{\partial g_2}\Delta g_2\\
  \frac{\Delta\bar{g}_m}{\bar{g}_m }&\simeq\frac{{g}_1}{\bar{g}_m }\frac{\partial\bar{g}_m}{\partial g_1}\frac{\Delta g_1}{g_1 }+\frac{{g}_2}{\bar{g}_m }\frac{\partial\bar{g}_m}{\partial g_2}\frac{\Delta g_2}{g_2}\\
  &=\alpha_1\frac{\Delta g_1}{g_1}+\alpha_2 \frac{\Delta g_2}{g_2}
  \end{align}\label{3}\tag{3}
  $$
  Assuming \eqref{3}, the I use one of the following two estimates:

  1. The "standard" error propagation theoretical estimate
     $$
     \left\vert\frac{\Delta\bar{g}_m}{\bar{g}_m }\right\vert\le|\alpha_1|\frac{\Delta g_1}{g_1}+|\alpha_2| \frac{\Delta g_2}{g_2}\label{I}\tag{I}
     $$
  2. A more refined estimates, that is an equality for the sum of normally distributed variables
     $$
     \left\vert\frac{\Delta\bar{g}_m}{\bar{g}_m}\right\vert\le\sqrt{\left(\alpha_1\frac{\Delta g_1}{g_1}\right)^{\!2}+\left(\alpha_2 \frac{\Delta g_2}{g_2}\right)^{\!2}}\label{II}\tag{II}
     $$

  I use almost always \eqref{I}. However, despite being optimal (from the value-to-cost ratio point of view) for medium/small production batches (from 100 to few thousands units per month), this estimates is too pessimistic and it would rise excessively the costs for large production batches, if I use it to chose the matching of $g_1$ and $g_2$ in order to get the desired matching on $\bar{g}_m$. On the other hand, \eqref{II} is a little bit more optimistic, but *how much is it more optimistic*?
- **A note after the comment of Nap D. Lover**. The parameters $g_1$ and $g_2$ are explicitly independent: *de facto*, they are associated to two different devices, even technologically very different.

Comment: I like the question...and my best regards from Sicily.

Comment: You say the correlation of $g_1$ and $g_2$ is zero. Are they also explicitly assumed to be independent as well? Just wondering.

Comment: @NapD.Lover yes. They are explicitly independent.

Comment: Thanks, @Sebastiano, and best regards from Romagna.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri $\frac{g_1g_2}{g_1+g_2}$ is half the harmonic mean of $g_1$ and $g_2$; Konstantinos Peppas has a paper where he considers two gamma random variables, maybe you can find some ideas for your normal distributed random variables.

PEPPAS, Kostas. Moments generating function of the harmonic mean of two non-identical gamma random variables and its applications in wireless communications. *Journal of the Franklin Institute*, 2012, 349.3: 845-860.

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson, thank you very much! Lemma 1 of Dr. Peppas paper is in reality a formula for the probability distribution function of the half harmonic mean \eqref{1} of two general random variables, therefore is much more than I required: and if you post your suggestion as can answer I'd be happy of upvoting it and accepting it. Best,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword here is *harmonic mean*.

$\frac{g_1g_2}{g_1+g_2}$ is half the harmonic mean of $g_1$ and $g_2$; Konstantinos Peppas has a paper<sup>1</sup> where he considers two gamma random variables, maybe you can find some ideas for your normal distributed random variables.

For your problem I found interesting [this Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268616/harmonic-mean-of-random-variables) (from where I get the reference to Peppas' paper) and [this other Q&A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6112/harmonic-mean-of-random-variables), from where I understood (I hope not to misunderstood it) that if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are distributed according a Cauchy then $\frac{g_1g_2}{g_1+g_2}$ is a Cauchy too.

**Reference**

<sup>1</sup>PEPPAS, Kostas. Moments generating function of the harmonic mean of two non-identical gamma random variables and its applications in wireless communications. *Journal of the Franklin Institute*, 2012, 349.3: 845-860.

Comment: Allessandro, I hope you do not mind if I took the liberty to format a little bit your question. Your answer solves a big problem and I have not resisted to "decorate it with bows".

Comment: @DanieleTampieri :-) fine