# References on (more or less) explicit calculations of probability distributions of nonlinear transformations of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request, reference-works

**Premise**. After a [former question and related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3624125/exact-determination-of-the-probability-distribution-of-a-nonlinear-function-of-t), I searched for references on the calculation of the probability distributions of nonlinear functions of (one or more) random variables, in order to build a firm basis for dealing with engineering problems which require such calculations in a rigorous manner.

**The question**

> *What are the works where the methods for calculating probability distributions of nonlinear transformation of random variables occupy a central place*?

I listed here a few guidelines in order to the ease answering to the question.

- The works should be *abstract* in the sense that the results they present should be *rigorous and widely applicable* (i.e. applicable to the widest range of problems, or abstract the Italian way).
- The "flavor" has to be *analytic* in the sense that the reference should deal with the problems in a constructive way by using techniques inherited from real and complex analysis.
- The work should aim at being comprehensive, therefore I prefer monographs/textbooks instead of single research works, even if survey papers on the topic are welcome.

**What I have already found**

Just to give a few examples, following more or less closely the above guidelines, I have identified the following works:

- Deutsch, R. *Nonlinear transformations of random processes*, (English) Prentice-Hall International Series in Applied Mathematics. Englewood Cliffs, N.J.: Prentice-Hall, Inc., pp. XI+157 (1962), [MR0148499](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0148499), [Zbl 0125.36801](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0125.36801).
- Rohatgi, V. K., *An introduction to probability theory and mathematical statistics* (English) Wiley Series in Probability and Mathematical Statistics. New York-Chichester-Brisbane: John Wiley & Sons, a Wiley-Interscience Publication, pp. XIV+684 (1976), [MR0407916](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0407916), [Zbl 0354.62001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0354.62001).
- Springer, M. D., *The algebra of random variables*, (English) Wiley Series in Probability and mathematical Statistics. New York-Chichester-Brisbane: John Wiley & Sons, pp. XIX+470 (1979), [MR0519342](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0519342), [Zbl 0399.60002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0399.60002).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this book will be very useful for  your purpose

[Probabilità e informazione](https://www.docenti.unina.it/webdocenti-be/allegati/materiale-didattico/528870)

I suggest you to read the whole book but, in particular,

- Chapter 4 for single rv
- Chapter 6 for pairs of rv's
- Chapter 8 for vectors of rv's

Comment: I apologize for the later in accepting your answer. The reference you pointed out is nice, though I hoped for answer citing more specialized monographs: perhaps there's a gap in the literature.